# How can you UPDATE a foreign key in a table using the value of an insert - in multiple rows simultaneously

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to UPDATE a foreign key in a table to the value that comes from a new insert, WHERE that key is currently null. The caveat here is that the information in the INSERT is related to the table.

Consider the example:

1. Car has a car_part
2. Both car and car_part have an association to version_control (a version_control has an id, from_version,to_version,active)
3. Some cars currently have a null version_control.
4. As a car has a car_part with a version_control, we essentially want to create a new version_control for the car and populate it with the same info as the car_part's version_control

Eg:

```
CAR
|id|car_part_id|version_control_id|
|1 |10         |                  |

CAR_PART
|id|version_control_id|
|10|100               |

VERSION_CONTROL
|id |from    |to         |
|100|1990    |2012       |
```

For the above example, we want to:

1. Update car 1,
2. Add a new version_control with the same info as version_control #100

In the real example, there are hundreds of cars, and dozens of them have null version_control_id's, so we this needs to be done in a single query.

How can we change the PSEUDO code below into valid SQL that solves this issue?

```
UPDATE car
WITH inserted_version as (
    INSERT INTO version_control(
            id, active, from_version_id, to_version_id)
    WITH vc_to_create as (
        select c.id as car_id,vc.* from car c
        inner join car_part cp on cp.id = c.car_part_id 
        inner join version_control vc on cp.version_control_id=vc.id
        where c.version_control_id IS NULL
        )
    SELECT nextval('pk_entities'),vctc.active, vctc.from_version_id, vctc.to_version_id)
    FROM vc_to_create vctc
    RETURNING id
    )
SET version_control_id=(SELECT i_vc.id  FROM inserted_vc i_vc)
WHERE id=vc_to_create.car_id -->vc_to_create Not available here
```

Comment: I am not sure where the `INSERT` takes place. Working from the sample data, which table gets an extra row and what are its contents?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - from the sample date, the version_control would get an extra column with values (101,1992,2012). Then the update would change car 1's version_control_id to 101. (notice 1992 and 2012 were copied from 100, because car 1 has car_part 10 and that car part has version control 100)

Comment: I don't know if this is clear, but essentially we're copying the version_control of car 1's car_part and associating it to the car)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do two modifications on different tables within a transaction block.

Here's a start. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-transactions.html

You also *might* need to set the transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE <s>prior to entering</s> within the transaction.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-transaction.html to understand what I'm talking about.

*Somebody please correct me if we don't need that strict an isolation level. My mind unfortunately gets fuzzy on the details of what scenarios strictly requires that level of isolation.  Strictly speaking, this may not need that isolation level, especially depending upon the SQL written, but this smells like it **might** be that kind of situation, however.  Just a possibly unnecessary forewarning.*

Edit:

Ok, you still don't need to do all this "in a single query".  Strictly speaking, you just need to identify or keep track of which rows were just inserted.  You should be able to use a temporary table for that.  That is:

1. Start transaction.
2. Set transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE. (Again, *if needed*, but I'd frankly be worried if I didn't set it, unless proved otherwise.  Also note using SERIALIZABLE you may have to retry: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)
3. Create temporary table as (using query)  the rows you will insert into version_control AS WELL AS the ids of the cars related to each version control line.  That is, each row will have version control info and id info.  We only need to grab `nextval('pk_entities')` here.
4. Insert into version control its data from the temporary table (as mentioned, we already generated the keys).
5. Update cars with data from temporary table.
6. Commit/drop table. (This can apparently be done on transaction commit when the table by declaring it in the temporary table's create statement.)

This us a bit of a high/mid level description of how I'd plan it, and as I haven't explicitly written code for that yet, I may have missed something.

Comment: while I understand transactions (and it would be trivial to perform one insert in version control and one update in car), the issue here is: how do you update both in the same query; otherwise I fail to see how you'd insert, say, 10 version controls with the correct information and then update them into the correct car - see the car/car_part/version_control example to understand the underlying issue9